# Unable to import from panar_utils in python

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

```
from planar_utils import plot_decission_boundary, sigmoid, load_planar_dataset
```

Giving this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError
Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-3-5aa22787d055> in <module>
      5 import sklearn.datasets
      6 import sklearn.linear_model
----> 7 from planar_utils import plot_decission_boundary, sigmoid, load_planar_dataset

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'planar_utils'
```

Comment: This means that the module has not been installed or was otherwise installed incorrectly or is unrecognized by Jupyter (as stated by tags). It is unlikely we could provide a sufficient answer to solve this issue, except for saying "just reinstall."

Comment: Do you know where the module `planar_utils` is supposed to come from?  Do you have documentation for it or whatever package it is a part of?  Have you properly installed that package?

Answer (score 2):

Copy the code, Make a python file. and import the file, use those functions.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import sklearn
import sklearn.datasets
import sklearn.linear_model

def plot_decision_boundary(model, X, y):
    # Set min and max values and give it some padding
    x_min, x_max = X[0, :].min() - 1, X[0, :].max() + 1
    y_min, y_max = X[1, :].min() - 1, X[1, :].max() + 1
    h = 0.01
    # Generate a grid of points with distance h between them
    xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.arange(x_min, x_max, h), np.arange(y_min, y_max, h))
    # Predict the function value for the whole grid
    Z = model(np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()])
    Z = Z.reshape(xx.shape)
    # Plot the contour and training examples
    plt.contourf(xx, yy, Z, cmap=plt.cm.Spectral)
    plt.ylabel('x2')
    plt.xlabel('x1')
    plt.scatter(X[0, :], X[1, :], c=y, cmap=plt.cm.Spectral)

def sigmoid(x):
    """
    Compute the sigmoid of x

    Arguments:
    x -- A scalar or numpy array of any size.

    Return:
    s -- sigmoid(x)
    """
    s = 1/(1+np.exp(-x))
    return s

def load_planar_dataset():
    np.random.seed(1)
    m = 400 # number of examples
    N = int(m/2) # number of points per class
    D = 2 # dimensionality
    X = np.zeros((m,D)) # data matrix where each row is a single example
    Y = np.zeros((m,1), dtype='uint8') # labels vector (0 for red, 1 for blue)
    a = 4 # maximum ray of the flower

    for j in range(2):
        ix = range(N*j,N*(j+1))
        t = np.linspace(j*3.12,(j+1)*3.12,N) + np.random.randn(N)*0.2 # theta
        r = a*np.sin(4*t) + np.random.randn(N)*0.2 # radius
        X[ix] = np.c_[r*np.sin(t), r*np.cos(t)]
        Y[ix] = j

    X = X.T
    Y = Y.T

    return X, Y

def load_extra_datasets():  
    N = 200
    noisy_circles = sklearn.datasets.make_circles(n_samples=N, factor=.5, noise=.3)
    noisy_moons = sklearn.datasets.make_moons(n_samples=N, noise=.2)
    blobs = sklearn.datasets.make_blobs(n_samples=N, random_state=5, n_features=2, centers=6)
    gaussian_quantiles = sklearn.datasets.make_gaussian_quantiles(mean=None, cov=0.5, n_samples=N, n_features=2, n_classes=2, shuffle=True, random_state=None)
    no_structure = np.random.rand(N, 2), np.random.rand(N, 2)

    return noisy_circles, noisy_moons, blobs, gaussian_quantiles, no_structure
```